# Price filter not showing proper price range in Magento 1.7

Tags: filter

Magento price filter on category page not showing proper price range on some category pages.

We have set price range Rs.1000 from magento admin section. Most of the categories are showing perfect product price range. For example

```
$ 0 - $ 1k
$ 1k - $ 2k
$ 2k - $ 3k
```

But some are showing categories it price range is coming Rs10k. For example

```
$ 0 - $10k
$ 10k - $20k
```

Please help me with this. If anyone have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking Magento tries to make a smart estimate on what the interval in the rate should be. For example, if you have a category with products that have a range between $0 and $100, the range slide will be in steps of $10.

But, if you have a category that has products varying from $0 to $10000, the range will probably be in steps of $1000.

A side-effect (feature) if this behaviour is if you have a situation where one product in your category is much more expensive than the rest. For example: let's say you have a category with 1000 products. 999 of those products are in the range of $0 to $100, but 1 product costs $9000. Magento will treat the category has having products in the range $0-$9000 and probably show intervals of $1000.

I'm not sure where in the part of the code you can alter this behaviour, or even if it's a configuration setting. The fact that you're running a very old version of Magento also isn't very helping.

I hope this information helps you somewhat.